# Error al subir imágenes con paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Saludos comunidad, estoy trabajando con **Ruby v2.2.6 y RoR v5.0.3** e intentando subir imágenes con **paperclip(4.3.7).** Al querer subir una imagen me arroja el siguiente error:

> ["Avatar Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError"]

Alguna sugerencia de cómo arreglar este error, de antemano gracias.!

Pd: Estoy trabajando sobre **Windows 10**, también instalé **ImageMagick-7.0.2-7-Q16**

Comment: ¿Es _ImageMagick-7.0.2-7-Q16-**x64**_ o _ImageMagick-7.0.2-7-Q16-**x86**-dll_?

Comment: **ImageMagick-7.0.2-7-Q16-x64**, pero ya pude resolver el problema tuve que descargar [este archivo] (https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/file/5.03/file-5.03-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=razaoinfo) y a agregar la ruta de instalación a las variables de entorno; luego agregar esta línea de código `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'` en **config/environments/development.rb** y el problema se solucionó.